# vb.net datagridview image column (change image - conditional)

Tags: vb.net, image, datagridview

I'm struggling with image column in my vb.net datagridview.
All what i want to do is that to change the image depending on a conditional time span.

Here is the full code :

```html
con.Open()
        da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(Q, con)
        da.Fill(ds)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        con.Close()

        Dim receivedfrom As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker1.Value)
        Dim receivedto As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker2.Value)
        Dim difference As TimeSpan
        Dim received As Date
        Dim today As Date = today
        Dim imgcol As New DataGridViewImageColumn()
        Dim inImg As Image = My.Resources.red
        imgcol.Image = inImg
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(imgcol)
        imgcol.HeaderText = ""
        imgcol.Name = "img"
        imgcol.DataPropertyName = "img"
        With DataGridView1
            .Columns("img").DisplayIndex = 1
            .Columns("img").Width = 28
            .Columns("AC_RECEIVEDDT").DisplayIndex = 2
        End With


        For rowIndex = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            received = DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("AC_RECEIVEDDT").Value
            difference = today.Subtract(received)

            If difference.Days < 2 Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("img").Value = My.Resources.green
            ElseIf difference.Days = 2 Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("img").Value = My.Resources.yellow
            Else
                DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("img").Value = My.Resources.red
            End If
        Next
```

Now, when i open the application, all the images are coming in RED color only.

I have added the column name = "img", that's why i got the images already, but my problem is that all the images are not being changed based on the received date value, all the images are showing in red.

My plan was to have the case with a time span less than 2 days to appear with green image as an acceptable processing period. Equal to 2 = yellow image. More than 2 days = red.

I do have the red image now for all the rows, but its not getting changed based on the if statement, all rows have RED as i have assigned it in the image column.

Goal:

[This is a DGV list with conditional status, that's exactly what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/093bU.png)

[That's what appears to me now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLmzx.png)

Clearly, it is not applying the IF statement, is there anything wrong ? Am i missing something ?

Hope the idea is clear enough.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: You did not set imgcol.name as "img'

Comment: a) The cellFormatting event or RowPrePaint event would be a better place to set the image rather than looping thru all the rows.  b) the bigger problem is that you are creating a new image object for each row.  If there are 300 red rows, you create 300 red images.  Eventually the app will run out of resources

Comment: What do you mean by running out of resources ?

Comment: What makes me use the loop, is to calculate each row time span (Received date & Today) based on the result i can determine which image to use. I never tried RowPrepaint event or CellFormating event, will it do the job ? Example please ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot provided does not show the values for the column `ac_receiveddt`. Anyway assuming it contains range of dates and you want to display the color based on the difference. Try below. Use `Days` instead of `TotalDays`.

```
If difference.Days < 2 Then
    DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("img").Value = My.Resources.Resource1.green
ElseIf difference.Days = 2 Then
    DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("img").Value = My.Resources.Resource1.yellow
End If
```

I have added check for DateTime conversion

```
For rowIndex = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1  
Dim rValue = DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("AC_RECEIVEDDT").Value
If DateTime.TryParse(rValue, received) Then
    difference = today.Subtract(received)

    If difference.Days < 2 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("img").Value = My.Resources.green
    ElseIf difference.Days = 2 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("img").Value = My.Resources.yellow
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("img").Value = My.Resources.red
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("not a DateTime")
End If  
Next
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i have uploaded a picture that contains the received date as well. Tried your solution but no affects.  Thanks !

Comment: @MohammedAbdulameer, Are you sure the cell value from ac_receiveddt is converted to DateTime received correctly. Did you put break point and debugged it. I am saying this because I have tried it on my PC and it worked gracefully. I have updated the code to test it it converts or not.

Comment: did u get any error message like "not a DateTime" ?

Comment: No, Its working fine with the same results
What i am thinking, i am retrieving the date from an ORACLE database, could that affect the way i am checking the datagridview cells ? in other words: should it be done in another way ?
i even tried to delete the column "received date" from the datagridview (Design view) and i added a new column called "new" using coding, i have done the same thing hoping that in codes, things will change, but unfortunately .. still the same. Thank you for your help

Comment: Put a break point at If difference.Days < 2 Then and see whats the value of difference and difference.Days

Comment: difference = 736050.00:00:00
difference.days = 736050
why the values doesn't make sense ?

Comment: For the comment above, i have used it before the IF statement, then i used it for the IF statement, it doesn't goes through the first 2 conditions, the value is always above 2 which is not correct. Which means either the declaration of the dates + time span variables is not correct, or the operation getting the timespan is not correct. Any help ?

Comment: I have fixed the values, changed the "Today" variable declaration from 
Dim today As Date = today
Dim today As Date = DateTime.Now

Also, i noticed that no matter what was the difference value (it's showing normal values now), the images still not being changed, so definitly im having a problem with the image column properties, statements. Appreciate any suggestion !
Also, no matter what was the dfference

Comment: I have added an image to show that it works fine on my system. Try changing imgcol.Name = "img" before DataGridView1.Columns.Add(imgcol) statement. Also make sure the yellow, green and red has different images in Resources. Or delete and add them again to resources.

Comment: My DGV is combined of 2 types of columns (columns filled from the DS and column created without a Data Property Name) 

The columns that are associated with the DS are populated successfully, but the columns that are not associated with the DS are empty.

When i am trying to fill the columns in a for loop (whether i write the column name or the column number) the program simply skip it and fill the following column (the following populated from the database) !!

Why it is ignoring ? i have no idea.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Please note that i can retrieve the data successfully from the DGV bu i cannot insert it in columns with no Data Property Name